# Web Load Test with MVC route parameters creates many instance URL's

Tags: asp.net-mvc, load-testing, web-testing

I have a web test for the following request:

```
{{WebServer1}}/Listing/Details/{{Active Listing IDs.AWE2_RandomActiveAuctionIds#csv.ListingID}}
```

And I receive the error message:

> The maximum number of unique Web test request URLs to report on has been exceeded; performance data for other requests will not be available

because there are thousands of unique URL's (because I'm testing for different values in the URL).  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Google provides lots of answers. Read about "reporting names".

Comment: I am using reporting names, and the individual URL's aren't showing up anymore, but it's still warning me that there are too many instance URL's...  Thank you though.

Comment: Visual Studio has lots of poorly documented customisation options available via registry and configuration files. Careful web searching *might* find a way of increasing the limit. Perhaps asking via Microsoft's own forums might get an answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few features within Visual Studio (2010 and above) that will help with this problem.  I am speaking for 2010 specifically, and assuming that the same or similar options are available in later versions as well.

**1.  Maximum Request URLs Reported:**

This is a General Option available in the Run Setting Properties of the load test.  The default value set here is 1,000.  This default value is usually sufficient... but not always high enough.  Depending on the load test size, it may be necessary to increase this.  Based on personal experience, if you are thinking about adjusting this value, go through your tests first and get an idea of how many requests you are expecting to see reported.  For me, a rough guideline that is helpful:

*number_of_request_in_webtest * number_of_users_in_load_test = total_estimated_requests*

If your load test has multiple web tests in it, adjust the above accordingly by figuring out the number of requests in each indvidual test, sum that value up, and multiply by the number of users.

This option is more appropriate for large load tests that are referencing several web tests and/or have a very high user count.  One reference for a problem|resolution use-case of this option is here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ffc16064-c6fc-4ef7-93b0-4decbd72167e/maximum-number-of-unique-web-test-requests-exceeded?forum=vstswebtest

In the specific case mentioned in the originally posted question, this would not resolve the problem entirely.  In fact, it could create a new one, where you end up running out of virtual memory. Visual Studio will continue to create new request metrics and counters for every single request that has a unique AWE2_RandomActiveAuctionIds.

**2.  Reporting Name:**

Another option, which @AdrianHHH already touched on, is the "Reporting Names" Option.  This option is found in the request properties, inside the web test.  It defaults to nothing, which in turn, results in Visual Studio trying to create the name that it will use from the request itself.  This behavior creates the issue you are experiencing.

This option is the one that will directly resolve the issue of a new request being reported for every unique request report.

If you have a good idea of the expected number of requests to be seen in the load test (and I think it is a good idea to know this information, for debugging purposes, when running into this exception) a debugging step would be to set the "Maximum Request URLs Reported" DOWN to that value. This would force the exception you are seeing to pop up more quickly.  If you see it after adjusting this value, then there is likely a request that is having a new reported value generated each time a virtual user executes the test.

Speaking from experience, this debugging step can save you some time and hair when dealing with requests that contain sessionId, GUID, and other similar types of information in them.  Unless you are explicitly defining a Reporting Name for every single request... it can be easy to miss a request that has dynamic data in it.

**3.  Record Results:**

Depending on the request, and its importance to your test, you can opt to remove it from your test results by setting this value to false.  It is accessed under the request properties, within the web test itself.  I personally do not use this option, but it may also be used to directly resolve the issue you are experiencing, given that it would just remove the request from the report all together.

A holy-grail-of-sorts document can be found on Codeplex that covers the Reporting Name option in a small amount of detail. At the time of writing this answer, the following link can be used to get to it:
http://vsptqrg.codeplex.com/releases/view/42484

I hope this information helps.